# Screen shot software

Tags: screen, capture

Ok guys, My work, when we need to send sites to review and editorial requires screenshots. we often need to screen shot entire websites and print them. it's a real pain in the butt especially when they make one change and want all new screenshots. right now we just use a firefox plugin that you need to right click, get screenshot etc. is there any program, software, plugin etc, that can either capture an entire directory or take a list of links and produce multiple images at once? anything?

Comment: Are you able to write some code, like C# for instance?

Comment: A quick search took me to this site: http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/. Looks like a best match for what you are looking for as long as your can write a script to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

We built an api driven solution around [IECapt](http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/) which we use to drive all the web thumbnails on one of our sites webtrendsnow.com. IECapt is nice in that it plays ball with any plugins etc that you might need (flash etc) and this is often the issue with some of the other more linux friendly solutions.

We were planning on making the API public, but we've been distracted by other projects and there didn't seem to be a huge demand.

We compiled the C# version of IECapt from source as we wanted to add in support for larger screen sizes IIRC. If you need the fix, let me know and I'll try to find it for you.

As for automating it, we wrote some simple scripts in perl to launch IECapt, get the output to a hires PNG, then use imagemagick to make cropped JPEGS etc.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the response. The goal is to have editors do this so that is probablly too much work for them, besides I'd like to avoid IE. I'm hoping there's an all in one built that can be plug and play